# Folder is not created when running from shortcut

Tags: eclipse-rcp, installation, nsis

Currently I am testing my Eclipse RCP appliction for Windows platform ( XP and above).

I am generating HTML pages at runtime. To save these HTML pages I am also creating a folder at runtime.

The folder is created at the same level where the exe file is located. 
Below is the application directory structure exactly how it looks:

```
MyApplication
    |
    |--MyApplication.exe
    |--Myapplication.ini
    |--artifacts.xml
    |--uninstall.exe
    |--configuration
    |--p2
    |--plugins
    |--workspace
    |--cache    (user defined folder)
         |
         |--system  (this is the runtime created folder, generated HTML pages are saved here)
           |
           |---
```

This is the code to create the folder at runtime:

```
String currentPath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
File folder = new File(currentPath+"/cache/system");
```

This all works fine.
Now using NSIS script I have created shortcuts for the ".exe" at two locations- One is on user desktop and other in StartMenu.

**The problem is, if I run the application from shortcut, the folder is not created.**
What should be done to solve this problem?

The script to create the shotcut is:

```
CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuGroup\MyApplication.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe"
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\MyApplication.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe"
```

Any comments/suggestions/solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should check if the path that you are using for the `File` constructor is ok at runtime, with a simple `println()` or whatever.
- Do you actually call the folder creation? Here you just show what the path is. To create a folder, don't forget to call `mkdir()` (or `mkdirs()` for a full path).
- in the NSIS side: the "working directory" for the shortcut might be wrong. The working directory is set from the current `$OUTDIR` when NSIS is processing the `CreateShortcut` directive.

  To be sure to set the working directory field of a shortcut, you can use the `SetOutPath` to force the directory. To use the directory where you install your application, just use `$INSTDIR`

  ```
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  ```

Comment: The problem is with my Java code. When I start the application from Shortcuts, the code `System.getProperty("user.dir")` treats the shortcut location as the Install directory. Accepting your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeYo: you're welcome :) Did you tried if you can change the `user.dir` property by setting manually the working directory in the shortcut? If yes, try also to fix the shortcut creation in nsis.

Comment: how to manually set the working dir in shortcut? are u refering to the target that the shortcut points to?
here the problem was from programming side... so I fixed it that way.

Comment: @JoeYo: i was refering to the dir from where the target is called when using the shortcut. It is an additionnal setting to the target path. And it is set from the current ouput path when nsis is creating the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

One problem i could see is :
if your installation location is in C:\Program Files.... then you might have to start the eclipse as Administrator.